# Appending -ed to irregular verbs, obscure dialect?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, dialect, irregular-forms

Some examples (born->borned, saw->sawed):

- Interview with Celia Black, Tyler, Texas, October 11, 1974 ([audio](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/afc/afc1975009/afc1975009_afs17476/afc1975009_afs17476.mp3), [transcript](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/afc/afc1975009/afc1975009_afs17476/afc1975009_afs17476.pdf))

  - Elmer Sparks (04:30): ...back when you were borned...
  - Elmer Sparks (04:38): ...time you were borned and where you were borned at....
- > Here it is. i know this man, I sawed him yesterday in the market. So the man is not a true human bean. — [Nairaland Forum](https://www.nairaland.com/5550938/friends-father-ghost/18)
- > "Yeah! I sawed him yesterday! Were all new peoples!" Keiko said smiling. — [Fanfic: Pre School Years and Ice Cream!](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1301258/1/Pre-School-Years-and-Ice-Cream)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There are multiple dialects with at least one of these forms. For example, since Nairaland is a Nigerian forum, it would seem that Nigerian English speakers use it.

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is.  Yes, these are non-standard.  No learners shouldn't use non-standard English in general. I voted to block answers, since I can't see a clear question to answer here.

Comment: Uneducated speech in the US often uses ED when the person does not know a verb's principle parts.

Comment: There is no question in your question. Although you have received an "answer", your question and the answer is liable to be closed (and become invisible to the public)  because it is not clear what's being asked. Please edit your question to explain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are many dialects of English. The most discussed on this site are British English, and US English. The differences between dialects are usually slight and are mainly related to spelling, some different common nouns, and idioms. There are no real grammar differences. And "borned" is not acceptable in any that I know of.

There are non-standard languages *based on* English, such as *pidgin* languages, and also *patois* which may have no literary form. It's possible that the speech you are quoting is partially influenced by one of these.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer
I provided the audio interview where I took that 'borned' part from, that guy was an American
Another example would be drown'ded (as in drowned-ed, when you say drowned you pronounce it as drown'd)

Comment: This is explained by uneducated speech where people do not know principal parts. In American unschooled speech an ed is often added to irregular verbs. So borned would reflect that. I sawed him is also like that; See, saw, seen. You also get: I seen him with the meaning I saw him. All this is very common in the American South.